# New Line Character in ONSEN ALERT

Tags: javascript, html, onsen-ui

I am using onsen alert for displaying error messages in javascript.
here is my code

```
var error="";
error = error.concat('\n\u2022',"FIRST LINE");
error = error.concat('\n\u2022',"SECOND LINE");
ons.notification.alert({message: error});
```

in output, i am getting bullets but they don't come in new line. 
i don't know how can i get message in new line in onsen alert. 
further, if i print same string with default javascript alert, all works fine. the lines do comes in new line. 
if anyone knows what's wrong/alternative solution then please do comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use HTML in your alert if you use the `messageHTML` parameter:

```
var error = '\u2022 FIRST LINE <br> \u2022 SECOND LINE';

ons.notification.alert({
  messageHTML: error
});
```

if you want an unordered list instead of bullet characters you can us the `<ul>` tag.

```
var error = '<ul style="text-align: left"><li>FIRST LINE</li><li>SECOND LINE</li></ul>';
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/argelius/pen/emMMOq

Comment: Sounds like OP should just use an unordered list. ;)